# write hard-codded to RAM at specific physical-address

Tags: c, linux, memory, userspace

I want write something in userspace program, for example: write the value `3` in the *physical* address `0xF7F4900(260MB)` from the start address `0x0`, while all kernel sits in the range 0-240MB.
How can I do it? any idea please?

Best regards.

I thought to use mmap but I think it gets me the *virtual* address.

```
memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
map = mmap(0xF7F4900, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memfd, 0);
*map = 3;
```

Comment: does `*((int*)0xF7F4900) = 3;` work?

Comment: @pmg Yes, but this address is the virtual address, isn't?

Comment: @jww OK, assume  I will do it,  how could I know that the value was written in the *physical* address?

Comment: I have no idea how kernel-mode (or whatever it's called) memory access works

Answer (score 0):

Treat `/dev/mem` as a file and write to offset `0xF7F4900` in that file:

```
char value = 3;
int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
lseek(fd, 0xF7F4900, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, &value, 1);
close(fd);
```

If you want to `mmap`, the same thing applies. You should not try to map it to `0xF7F4900` in *your* process, you should instead map it to an arbitrary location and write to `map[0xF7F4900]` if you map from offset 0 or `map[0x900]` if you map from the page boundary `0xF7F4000`.

Note that arbitrary access to `/dev/mem` may require special kernel configuration, and is disabled entirely with UEFI Secure boot.

Comment: shouldn't it be `write(fd, &value, sizeof value);`? NVM, value is char in your code :O

Comment: when I try:
    int val = 5;
    lseek(fd, 0xF7F4900, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, &val, sizeof(int));
the write() failed with error of bad_address :O

And then we back to my question: how to write a value to specific physical address in RAM?

thanks

Answer (score -4):

That's not possible in most operating systems as you could gain control over the system. [Only one of the thousands vulnerabilitys](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: How does a link about PHP help here?